# Variable is "not declared" when read from outside of curly brackets

Tags: javascript

I am trying to declare a variable inside of curly brackets, then call the variable outside of the curly brackets, but I get an error: 
`ReferenceError: myVar is not defined`

Ex:

```js
{
let myVar = "string"
}
console.log(myVar)
```

Comment: JavaScript is telling you this isn't allowed because the variable is no longer in scope. You will need to find a different solution to your original problem. Why do you think you need to do this? How are you trying to use it? Please show a code example where you want to do this and we an suggest a different approach.

Comment: I am using discord.js and I am trying to make a command that when run sends the contents of a variable and I get to change what the contents of that variable is in another command.

Comment: Please add information about "a command" and "another command". Maybe some shortened function that contains the described commands.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to illustrate these commands.

Comment: By "command" I mean that my code is checking if a message is sent with the specified contents, then will run the code.

Comment: "I get to change what the contents of that variable is in another command" This sounds like you are concentrating too much on how to implement a solution to a problem in code before determining what the solution should do at a higher level. I suggest you describe in words what each of these commands are supposed to do. Avoid using words like "variable" that are tied to your code. Instead, explain what the input should be and what the output or other results should be.

Comment: @MrAuro That still doesn't really clarify what you are doing. JavaScript doesn't have "commands". In order for us to help you, please show some code showing what you have tried so far. It needs to include more details than what you have already shown. See the link in my previous comment for some tips on how to create a good code example.

Comment: It sounds like you are creating a plugin for Discord. Is that correct? If so, you should state that in your question when you [edit] it to include the code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up on scoping.

The let variable has a local scope, and thus cannot be accessed outside of its local scope.

You can use var, which has a global scope and can be accessed anywhere, or you can declare myVar outside of the curley brackets to give it a larger scope range.